# Remove all previous Buy Sell signals except the last one

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator, pine-script-v4

Is it possible to remove all previous **Long** and **Short** signals Except the last one..? Here is the code

```
`long = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1
short = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1
alertcondition(long, title="Long", message="Long")
alertcondition(short, title="Short", message="Short")`
```

Here what i use after searching on google

```
`var lastLong = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1
var lastShort = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1

var long = false
var short = false

if (lastLong)
    long := true
else if (lastShort)
    short := true
else
    na`
```

But it doesn't work. and it doesn't even show the ongoing signals.

Comment: What do you mean by removing signals? Do you want to remove the labels?

Comment: Yes... is it possible...? Except for the current one... Means if "Long" signal come then it should stay here at least when no new signal comes in. And it should also remove all previous labels.

or may be is it possible to save all labels within specific time and remove all other labels from previous time... ?

Comment: Where are the labels or plotshapes in your code?

Comment: plotshape(long, title="Long", text="Long", style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.black, size=size.tiny, location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime, transp=0)

Comment: OH so much sorry... i just worked on this by removing plot shapes ... and I was very shocked that this is not my problem... now it's confirmed that i need  all the previous condition **false** and all incoming condition **True**.. Just like what i tried before(the code in my question which i tried after searching on google and it didn't work for me)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the shapes created by `plotshape()`.

If that is your goal, you should use `label`s instead.

You would do it by creating a new label whenever your condition is `true` and deleting the old one.

```
// Create a new label
lbl = label.new(bar_index, high, "Buy", yloc=yloc.belowbar, style=label.style_label_up)

// Delete the old label
label.delete(lbl[1])    // Delete the old label
```